# Javascript messes with orderBy in my CRUD in Laravel Backpack

Tags: laravel-backpack

I followed [the process in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40334901/what-are-the-reordering-columns-on-laravel-backpack) and everything works, but I wanted to see the order in my displayed page.

I updated My controller with this:

```
$this->crud->orderBy('lft');
```

But it doesn't seem to work. I then desactivated the JavaScript, and the order was correct. It seems the JS reorders the contents when loading the page (I assume it's by the contents IDs).

How can I disable this behaviour ? (Only the one made while loading the page, I want my users to be able to reorder by columns).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was a bug - DataTables ignored the order set by Eloquent and just did his thing. This has been fixed in the latest version of Backpack\CRUD, so a `composer update` should fix it.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try it as soon as I can!